# ngFor crashes when adding new items to collection after animation in Nativescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, ngfor

I have views placed one over another using **ngFor**. Sort of cards:

```
<GridLayout rows="*">
    <GridLayout row="0" *ngFor="let image of images; trackBy: trackByList"
        verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"
        [width]="width" [height]="width" (loaded)="itemLoaded($event)"
        [rotate]="getRotationAngle(image)" [style.z-index]="image.zIndex">
        <Image [src]="image.path" [id]="image.zIndex" stretch="aspectFill"
            [width]="width" [height]="width">
        </Image>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>


itemLoaded(event) {
    let grid: any = event.object;

    grid.on(GestureTypes.swipe, (args: SwipeGestureEventData) => {
        if (this.animationIsRunning) {
            return;
        }
        let x = this.width * 1.5;
        let rotate = 45;

        if (args.direction == SwipeDirection.right) { }
        else if (args.direction == SwipeDirection.left) {
            x *= -2;
            rotate *= -1;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }


        this.animationIsRunning = true;
        grid.animate({ translate: { x: x, y: 0 }, opacity: 0, rotate: rotate, duration: 500 })
            .then(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.swipeFinished();
                }, 10);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.message);
            })
    })
}
// 
private swipeFinished() {
    this.swipedImages++;

    if (this.images.length - this.swipedImages <= 2) {

        console.log("Requesting next page");
        this.addNextPage();
        console.log("Next page loaded. Refreshing changes.");
        this.cdr.detectChanges();

        this.animationIsRunning = false;
    }
    else {
        this.animationIsRunning = false;
    }
}
trackByList(index, item: ImageObj) {
    return item.zIndex;
}
```

I'm loading **items** from server using pages mechanism. 5 each time.
After loading next page and inserting new elements in to **items** and calling **this.cdr.detectChanges()** I get crash"

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'destroyed' of null ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyed' of null

- I'm using ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush
- Looks like this is due to swipe animation

[**Playground example** (Need to do swipes in order to trigger reload and crash)](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jUcKJB&v=5)

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "Extending Collection". But just placing views one on another shouldn't crash, it could be something else. Can you share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I've updated my question and added a link to playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code, I see two major reasons for the crash.

- You are running swipe event outside Angular context, indeed you were manually triggering the change detection, but I doubt it was done on right time.
- Also, you were not cleaning up your array post animation, so over time there could be 100s of Images eventually affect your performance too.

Here is the [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jUcKJB&v=7), the crash seems to be fixed on my end. But honestly it could be still improved. I would recommend taking a look at the blog post on [Tinder Style Cards with NativeScript Angular](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tinder-style-cards-with-nativescript---love-at-first-swipe) by Jen Looper, that might help you on improving your design.

Comment: Thanks Manoj. The playground is not exactly my design. It was written quickly in order to show the problem.However if I understand correctly what fixed the problem is a (swipe) event definition inside the html? Also I do not understand why my swipe event was running outside the Angular context?

Comment: You were running it outside Angular context, you are not suppose to add event listeners yourself in component, if you do you should use renderer to add listeners otherwise its outside zone by default.